# How to update remote tables with local database table with same primary key?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I want to update remote tables of a database from the local database tables.
But when i update for the masters i am fackign problem of mismatch primary key.
So is there a mechanism that i can update remote database tables with same primary key at local. If i delete a record at local there is mismatch of primary key at remote.
Although i have both type of table with no primary key, and with primary key.

Here i did it like this

IF table at local with primary key.

```
  public bool PublishDressingDetails()
        {
            int isUpdated = -1;
            try
            {
                DataTable DressingDetailsLocalDT = cDressing.GetAllDressingDetailsDTForExport();
                if (DressingDetailsLocalDT.Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    //SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Toppings where ClientID=2", connWeb);
                    SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from DressingDetails", connWeb);

                    DA.InsertCommand.Transaction = transaction;
                    DA.UpdateCommand.Transaction = transaction;
                    DA.DeleteCommand.Transaction = transaction;

                    SqlCommandBuilder SCB = new SqlCommandBuilder(DA);

                    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
                    DA.Fill(DS, "DressingDetails");
                    //DS.Tables[0].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { DS.Tables[0].Columns["ClientID"], DS.Tables[0].Columns["ToppingID"] };
                    DS.Tables[0].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { DS.Tables[0].Columns["DressingID"] };

                    object[] searchVal = new object[1];
                    //searchVal[0] = "2";

                    //DataRow drSrc;
                    foreach (DataRow drLocal in DressingDetailsLocalDT.Rows)
                    {
                        searchVal[0] = drLocal["DressingID"].ToString();
                        DataRow drSrc = DS.Tables[0].Rows.Find(searchVal);
                        if (drSrc == null)
                        {
                            drSrc = DS.Tables[0].NewRow();
                            //drSrc["ClientID"] = "2";
                            drSrc["DressingID"] = drLocal["DressingID"].ToString();

                            if (drLocal["Description"] != DBNull.Value)
                            {
                                drSrc["Description"] = drLocal["Description"].ToString();
                            }
                            else drSrc["Description"] = DBNull.Value;

                            if (drLocal["Position"] != DBNull.Value)
                            {
                                drSrc["Position"] = drLocal["Position"].ToString();
                            }
                            else drSrc["Position"] = DBNull.Value;


                            if (drLocal["IsDeleted"] != DBNull.Value)
                            {
                                drSrc["IsDeleted"] = drLocal["IsDeleted"].ToString();
                            }
                            else drSrc["IsDeleted"] = DBNull.Value;


                            if (drLocal["icon"] != DBNull.Value)
                                drSrc["icon"] = drLocal["icon"];
                            else
                                drSrc["icon"] = DBNull.Value;


                            DS.Tables[0].Rows.Add(drSrc);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //drSrc["ClientID"] = "2";
                            drSrc["DressingID"] = drLocal["DressingID"].ToString();
                            if (drLocal["Description"] != DBNull.Value)
                            {
                                drSrc["Description"] = drLocal["Description"].ToString();
                            }
                            else drSrc["Description"] = DBNull.Value;

                            if (drLocal["Position"] != DBNull.Value)
                            {
                                drSrc["Position"] = drLocal["Position"].ToString();
                            }
                            else drSrc["Position"] = DBNull.Value;

                            if (drLocal["IsDeleted"] != DBNull.Value)
                            {
                                drSrc["IsDeleted"] = drLocal["IsDeleted"].ToString();
                            }
                            else drSrc["IsDeleted"] = DBNull.Value;


                            if (drLocal["icon"] != DBNull.Value)
                                drSrc["icon"] = drLocal["icon"];
                            else
                                drSrc["icon"] = DBNull.Value;
                        }

                    }
                    isUpdated = DA.Update(DS, "DressingDetails");

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            return (isUpdated != -1) ? true : false;
        }
```

With no primary key.

```
  public bool PublishMealDealDetail()
        {
            bool isUpdated = true;
            try
            {
                DataTable dtLocal = libEPOS.cMealDeal.GetAllMealDealDetailsDTForExport();
                if (dtLocal.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    //truncate table on web
                    string sqlTrunc = "TRUNCATE TABLE MealDealDetail";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlTrunc, connWeb, transaction);
                    // connWeb.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connWeb);
                    bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "MealDealDetail";
                    try
                    {
                        bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dtLocal);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        isUpdated = false;
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                isUpdated = false;
                throw ex;
            }

            return isUpdated;
        }
```

Comment: "So is there a mechanism that i can update remote database tables with same primary key at local" look into database replication, no need code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U can make use of `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity` to keep identity from one source to other source while updating tables.

MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopyoptions(v=vs.110).aspx

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(connWeb,System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity);
```